# Create scrollable ListView with static items using just XML layout

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, android-adapter, android-adapterview

I want to display a static ListView like `Settings > About Phone` without creating an Adapter to handle multiple view types etc. What XML layout simulates this exactly? It needs to look exactly like a ListView and have the same divider between items according to the application theme etc.

Comment: I would suggest you to create simple layout of all the types of view for whichever resolution you want to show your page with the static content and load it as an activity.

Comment: Any examples of what you've tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the same XML from the list item templates for each item.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:overScrollMode="ifContentScrolls" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:divider="?android:attr/dividerHorizontal"
        android:showDividers="middle" >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItem"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
            android:paddingRight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingRight"
            android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: An old question, however, to actually give it a list item style, you have to set `true` to both `android:focusable` and `android:clickable` in your TextView XML as well.